# How to show two SizedBox() in if else?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to show two SizedBox() in if else. I put if else inside `children: <Widget>[]` like this code.

```
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          child: Row(

            children: <Widget>[
              if (n == 1)

                SizedBox(
                  child: TextButton(
                    child: Image.asset('images/a.jpg'),
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  child: TextButton(
                    child: Image.asset('images/b.jpg'),
                  ),
                )

              else     //////////////////// error this line
                SizedBox(
                  child: TextButton(
                    child: Image.asset('images/b.jpg'),
                  ),
                ),
                
                 SizedBox(
                    child: TextButton(
                      child: Image.asset('images/a.jpg'),
                    ),
                    )
              ],
```

At line `else` it show error like this.

```
Expected to find ']'.
```

I think `]` should put under `else`. How to show two SizedBox() in if else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use spread operator with a List of Widgets.

```dart
if( something )
    ...[ SizedBox(), SizedBox(), SizedBox() ]
```

So you need to do it the following way:

```dart
if( n == 1 )
    ...[ SizedBox(), SizedBox(), SizedBox() ],
if( n != 1 )
    ...[ Container(), Container() ],
```

```dart
if( n == 1 )
    ...[ SizedBox(), SizedBox(), SizedBox() ],
else
    ...[ Container(), Container() ],
```

```dart
      if (n == 1) ...[
          SizedBox(
            child: TextButton(
              child: Image.asset('images/a.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            child: TextButton(
              child: Image.asset('images/b.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        if (n != 1) ...[
          SizedBox(
            child: TextButton(
              child: Image.asset('images/b.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            child: TextButton(
              child: Image.asset('images/a.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
```

Comment: @user58519 I've actually encountered that there actually is an **else** operator. The comment a bit lower of this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (n == 1)...[
        SizedBox(
          child: TextButton(
            child: Image.asset('images/a.jpg'),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          child: TextButton(
            child: Image.asset('images/b.jpg'),
          ),
        )
      ]
      else...[
        SizedBox(
          child: TextButton(
            child: Image.asset('images/b.jpg'),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          child: TextButton(
            child: Image.asset('images/a.jpg'),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also done like this
--- separate your condition using (Ternary conditional operator)  :

```
n==1? Column(
            children: [
                  SizedBox(
                   child: TextButton(
                    child: Image.asset('images/a.jpg'),
                     ),
                   ),
                   SizedBox(
                     child: TextButton(
                      child: Image.asset('images/b.jpg'),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ):   /// here 
                Column(
                 children: [
                   SizedBox(
                    child: TextButton(
                     child: Image.asset('images/a.jpg'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      child: TextButton(
                       child: Image.asset('images/b.jpg'),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ],
                   )
```